# Devise after_create in overrided RegistrationsController, Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I need to call after_create :something inside overrided Devise class RegistrationsController.
Like this:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  after_create :something
end
```

But it does't work:

> undefined method `after_create' for
>   RegistrationsController:Class

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`after_create` is an ActiveRecord hook, not a controller hook. Maybe you're looking for `after_filter`?